# VS 2010 WCF service reference https connection error

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, certificate

I've got an error while updating WCF service reference in Visual Studio 2010:

There was an error downloading 'https://192.16.0.76/MyService.svc'.
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://192.16.0.76/MyService.svc'.
The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Two weeks ago reference update worked fine and nothing was changed in web.config file. Now I can't update service reference and add new features to the Silverlight application. I've looked for answer on the Internet and most people advice to check certificates on the developer's pc. I haven't canged any certificates fon my pc and I also add ny certificate to the local machine store as well. Maybe I should change the default certicate for Visual Studio but I can't find how to do this.

Here is my web.config file :

```
  <source name="System.ServiceModel"
      switchValue="Error,Warning"
      propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener"
              name="Default">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
      <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </listeners>
  </source>

  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging"
  switchValue="Warning, Error">
    <listeners>
      <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
      <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>

<sharedListeners>

  <add initializeData="tracelog.svclog"
      type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, 
                    Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
      name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
    <filter type="" />
  </add>
  <add initializeData="messages.svclog"
      type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, 
                    System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
      name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
    <filter type="" />
  </add>
</sharedListeners>

<trace autoflush="true" />
```

```
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="600" />
```

```
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="MyForm.Web.MyService.customBinding0"
         receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"

           openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00">
      <binaryMessageEncoding/>
      <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="CertificateWithTransport" 
           receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
           openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="Transport" >
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"  />
      </security>
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2640000"
               maxStringContentLength="2000000000"
               maxArrayLength="2000000000"
               maxBytesPerRead="2000000000"
               maxNameTableCharCount="2000000000" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="MyForm.Web.MyService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CertificateWithTransport"
      contract="MyForm.Web.MyService" />
  </service>
</services>
<diagnostics >
  <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true"             
   logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
   logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" 
    />
</diagnostics>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

[Upd] It seems that it can be caused by problems with certificate on my pc. How can I choose the certificate that will be used for https connection to the web service ? I've found similar [topics](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/b884f7f3-10c2-43df-bfb9-1e53a247efaf) on the internet but there were no solutions for it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Going through [WCF – 2 Way SSL Security using Certificates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/imayak/archive/2008/09/12/wcf-2-way-ssl-security-using-certificates.aspx) , might help you.

Comment: I have read that article. It contains information about configuring SSL for WCF. But I have already configured it. Silverlight application has no problem connecting to WCF but Visual Studio cannot update service reference.